# Activity Diagram with multiple end points

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

My Question may be simple, but I am confused because I have no idea about activity diagrams.

My question- Are multiple end points ever acceptable in an activity diagram?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit touchy to reference IBM though they are one of the big OMG parents. The "truth" is written in OMG's superstructures.

Actually UML2.5 talks about `Final Node` in the context of activity diagrams:

> **Final Nodes**
>
> A FinalNode is a ControlNode at which a flow in an Activity stops. A FinalNode shall not have outgoing ActivityEdges. A FinalNode accepts all tokens offered to it on its incoming ActivityEdges.
>
> There are two kinds of FinalNode:
>
> 1. A FlowFinalNode is a FinalNode that terminates a flow. All tokens accepted by a FlowFinalNode are destroyed. This has no effect on other flows in the Activity.
> 2. An ActivityFinalNode is a FinalNode that stops all flows in an Activity ...

A `ControlNode` is a kind of `ActivityNode` and those form `Activities`. The definition except in the context of the `FinalNode` does not tell how the single `ActivityNode`s can be related. So from that you can have as many as you like/need.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there may be cases where multiple endpoints are acceptable.

> It is possible for an activity diagram to show multiple final states.
> Unlike initial state symbols, of which there can be only one on an
> activity diagram, final state symbols can represent the termination of
> one of many branches in the logic -- in other words, the activity may
> terminate in different manners.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep03/f_umlbasics_db.pdf
(Page 5)

See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215071/do-activity-diagrams-always-end-in-one-endpoint

Comment: Its not true that an activity diagram must not have several initial nodes. And btw it is "initial node" not "initial state" because we are talking about activity diagrams and not about statemachines, right? That let aside, the formal specification of UML 2.5.1 says clearly on p. 387 about initial nodes that there may be several of them in an activity. If there are several initial nodes, there is parallelity.